# How would I parse this or convert this into JSON?

Tags: php, json, flash, apache-flex, rtmp

```
{
  name: 'com.riotgames.platform.summoner.PublicSummoner',
  keys: [ 'internalName', 'dataVersion', 'acctId', 'name', 'profileIconId', 'revisionDate', 'revisionId', 'summonerLevel', 'summonerId', 'futureData' ],
  object: {
    internalName: 'mrquackers',
    dataVersion: 0,
    acctId: { value: 34117327 },
    name: 'MrQuackers',
    profileIconId: 502,
    revisionDate: Tue, 30 Oct 2012 19:38:32 GMT,
    revisionId: { value: 0 },
    summonerLevel: { value: 30 },
    summonerId: { value: 20933307 },
    futureData: null
  },
  encoding: 0
}
```

(newlines and indentation added by editor; not part of the response)

It's a response from an RTMP packet and I'm not sure how I would go about parsing it.
Is there a library in php or a way I can convert this into something easily parsable like json?

Comment: json_decode json_encode. Infact just typing in "PHP JSON" in to Google  would have given you this answer.

Comment: that pretty much is json. only thing that is different about json is usually it uses double quotes and the keys are supposed to have quotes around them. json_decode should still work in php and in JS JSON.parse() might still work, not sure if it validates.

Comment: I've tried it with json_decode in PHP and it returns null

Comment: This doesn't look like any valid standard information exchange format. It looks like you'll have to parse it manually.

Comment: @rid well, it is _almost_ json.

Comment: If you can add the quotes manually, you can then decode with json_decode

Comment: Not really... Take a look at the value of the `revisionDate` key...

Comment: @rid ouch. That would need quoting as well

Comment: @JanDvorak, and quoting that automatically is not easy... There's great pain and error prone code in the future of this project if the source of this data can't be convinced to output something more parsable.

Comment: @rid It _might_ be possible in a kludgy way. Not saying it's a great idea, though

Comment: @JanDvorak, also, if this data looks so irregular, there's no telling what other data types the source will come up with, if there's no previously-agreed-upon standard for exchange.

Comment: Should I add some formatting to the response sample (while clarifying that I did so) to make it more readable?

Comment: @rid Admitted. You _could_ still assume that a _key_ is a _sequence of alphanumeric chars before a colon_ and that everything that isn't a _key_ is a _value_ ;-)

Comment: @JanDvorak, that would mean that you have the key `revisionDate` with the value `Tue` and the key `30 Oct 2012 19` with the value `38` or some other unparsable thing for such as simple parser. This unquoted date string messes everything up, and the uncertainty of what future data will contain makes any parser a time bomb...

Comment: @rid so, from colon to comma? ... No, that won't work either :-/

Comment: @rid isn't this format for date HTTP-compliant? IF you can assume that all unqoted values that start with a letter are dates, THEN you can actually parse this response. Anyone dares to make this guarantee? :-)

Comment: @JanDvorak, unquoted values can also be integers, floats and nulls according to this sample. You'd need to make a lexer to tokenize this, and PHP is probably not the ideal language to implement lexers in...

Comment: Oh, a _null_ also starts with a letter :-/

Answer (score 1):

No. It is not possible to automatically parse a response if you don't know the language it uses.

While the response *looks* like JSON, it isn't. It's not even *close* to JSON. You can't just quote the keys to make it valid JSON.

Except for the `revisionDate`, it *seems* to be valid Javascript, but who knows?

The parser needs to know every data type it might potentially encounter. There's no telling what could appear in the response. Unless you find the documentation for this format, you never know what you might encounter.

You could *in theory* be able to parse the language you *think* this response is. But

1. you need to implement your own parser. That's not easy. At all.
2. you cannot assume you *know* the responder language. This response is *one value* from being valid javascript.
3. a poorly implemented parser will not even know it met something it doesn't understand. Instead of giving up, it will produce unexpected results
4. if you modify your model of the language, if your parser isn't a full-blown parser, incorporating the change into the parser could easily lead to a complete rewrite of the parser.

**Conclusion:**

You don't know the language the responder talks in. This means you cannot parse it. Find the documentation first, *then* talk about parsing.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Flash/AS3 to receive this packet, you could use the [as3corelib JSONDecoder](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib) Class.

Here is an example using the JSON sample you provided:

```
import com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON;

var raw:String = "{ name: 'com.riotgames.platform.summoner.PublicSummoner', keys: [ 'internalName', 'dataVersion', 'acctId', 'name', 'profileIconId', 'revisionDate', 'revisionId', 'summonerLevel', 'summonerId', 'futureData' ], object: { internalName: 'mrquackers', dataVersion: 0, acctId: { value: 34117327 }, name: 'MrQuackers', profileIconId: 502, revisionDate: Tue, 30 Oct 2012 19:38:32 GMT, revisionId: { value: 0 }, summonerLevel: { value: 30 }, summonerId: { value: 20933307 }, futureData: null }, encoding: 0 }";
// 1. Add quotes to all keys. 2. Wrap string around date object. 3. Replace single quotes with double quotes.
raw = raw.replace(/([\w]+): /g, "'$1': ").replace(/\w+, \d* \w+ \d* \d*:\d*:\d* \w+/g, "'$&'").replace(/'/g, "\"");

var json:Object = JSON.decode(raw, false);
var date:Date = new Date(json.object.revisionDate);

trace(json.name); // "com.riotgames.platform.summoner.PublicSummoner"
trace(date.month); // 9
```

Comment: It's not that difficult to make the JSON valid. Plus, the decoder Class has an option to accept strict JSON strings or not. I have updated my answer to demonstrate.

Comment: Still, how does it handle the `revisionDate` value?

Comment: Assuming the date structure is consistent (which it appears to be a UTC string date object), the regEx above wraps the date in a string. You can then parse the date using the Date Class. I've added this example to the answer.

Comment: As per my discussion with `rid`, there is too little data to conclude you know the language

Comment: ... unless a string contains a substring that looks like a date. Then it will break.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do. The only issue here is with the revisionDate, which would better be converted into a timestamp to be processed by ActionScript (or into a string, if you like) so I would use the [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) function to change it for the former condition or the [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) function for the latter condition:

```
// this is for numeric timestamp: 1351625912
$str = preg_replace_callback('~(?<=\srevisionDate:\s).+?(?=,\n|,\r|,\r\n)~',
create_function('$m','return strtotime($m[0]);'),$str);

// alternatively, you can wrap it with single quotes: 'Tue, 30 Oct 2012 19:38:32 GMT'
//$str = preg_replace('~(?<=\srevisionDate:\s).+?(?=,\n|,\r|,\r\n)~',"'$0'",$str);

echo $str;
```